# How to instantiate a map of structs in thrift?

Tags: thrift

I want to store some mapped metadata that need to be accessed across FE and BE and different languages. Thus ideally the data should be stored a thrift file.
The data should be mapped between an enum as the key, and a struct to store multiple metadata.
I would avoid creating multiple maps given the number of keys will be big and it will be hard to maintain multiple maps.
I found we can do this:

```
const map<string, string> str_map = {
  'a': 'b',
  ...
}
```

Ideally it should look like this:

```
const map<Enum, StructName> data_map = {
  Enum.A: StructForA{...},
  Enum.B: StructForB{...} 
  ...
}
```

but I cant figure out a way to instantiate a struct in thrift file. Is it possible?

Alternatively a slightly worser but acceptable solution will be:

```
const map<Enum, map<FieldNameEnum, UnionDataType>> data_map = {
  Enum.A: {Field1: XXX, Field2: YYY},
  ...
}
```

But the question is how to define the UnionDataType? If use a `union` then how to instantiate it?

If not possible, then I can accept something like this:

```
const map<Enum, str> data_map = {
Enum.A: json_str_for_a_metadata,
...
}
```